# структура базы данных для подписок

Tags: php, mysqli

как структурировать базу данных, для системы подписок/подписчиков? тоесть есть юзер который подписывается на другого, и у юзера что подписался, выводятся на главной новости того на кого подписан. а другой юзер в свою очередь просто видет своих подписчиков. без всяких заявок в друзья

Comment: Многие ко многим, не?

Comment: Таблица с двумя полями: ID-того-кто-подписался, ID-на-кого-подписан. Первичный ключ - оба поля вместе.

Answer (score 1):

Приведу первый пришедший в голову минимум.

Table `Users`:

```
id    INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
name  varchar(255) NOT NULL
email varchar(255) NOT NULL
....
```

Table `News`:

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
title varchar(255) NOT NULL
user_id int(11) NOT NULL [INDEX] 
content text 
....
```

Table `Subscribe`

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
user_id int(11) NOT NULL [INDEX] 
subscribe_id int(11) NOT NULL [INDEX]
```